# Get corresponding value for specific tag - XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSLT to parse through an XML document and there is a block that contains repeated element names and I want to grab a certain value that corresponds to a certain tag value.
Here is an example of what the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tags>
        <tag>
            <tag_id>TEST_TAG1</tag_id>
            <tag_value>TEST_VALUE1</tag_value>
        <tag>
        <tag>
            <tag_id>TEST_TAG2</tag_id>
            <tag_value>TEST_VALUE2</tag_value>
        <tag>
        <tag>
            <tag_id>TEST_TAG3</tag_id>
            <tag_value>TEST_VALUE3</tag_value>
        <tag>
    </tags>
</root>
```

I am using XSLT 2.0.
How can I grab the value "TEST_VALUE2" by checking the tag_id for "TEST_TAG2"?

So basically, I would like to check for a certain tag_id value and save its tag_value value into a variable like this:

```
    if(tag_id == "TEST_TAG2")
    {
        value = <tag_value> // tag_value element related to the tag_id value TEST_TAG2
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath for that would be this

```
root/tags/tag[tag_id='TEST_TAG2']/tag_value
```

You can of course adjust that to whatever context you might need it in so long as you use the correct [predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Predicates). Otherwise, you just put that into the select of a `value-of` and that should be it.